# Linear Algebra Notation of a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

$$O(3) = \{A \in M |  A^\top A = I\}$$

Ok, so the first part I know means that $A$ is a subset/element of $M$. Does the second part mean that the transpose of $A$ multiplied by itself is always the identity matrix, and if that is not the case, it is not part of the subset. Is my understanding of this correct.

Comment: Everything to the right of the bar is a condition. Any element in this set must satisfy this property (that is, a matrix is orthogonal if its transpose is its inverse).

Comment: The symbol $\in$ means “element of,” not “subset of.”

Answer (score 4):

You've understood the definition correctly.  One usually reads it off as follows:
$$
\overbrace{\{ }^{\text{the set of}} \overbrace{A \in M}^{\text{(matrices) $A$ in $M$}} \overbrace{\mid}^{\text{such that}} A^TA = I\}
$$